# How to create custom admin page which is not visible in admin menu in WordPress CMS?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a new plugin, registered a new admin menu page, and added a few submenu pages.  One of the pages has a doctors list, and each doctor is picked up from the database.

I want to have an "edit" link near each doctor.  The link has to take the client to an edit page.  How do I register this page without showing as submenu page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution. You have to create two submenu pages one under another, secound page will not be showed in admin panel.
Goes like this:

```
  add_submenu_page( 'dev7d-father','Daktarai','Daktarai', 'manage_options' , 'dev7d-sub-doctors', 'doctors_options');
        add_submenu_page( 'dev7d-sub-doctors','Daktarų redagavimas','Daktarų redagavimas', 'manage_options' , 'dev7d-sub-doctors-edit', 'doctors_edit');
```